# Subdomain instead of a Subfolder with Apache Reverse Proxy?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, subdomain, regex

[The Lounge](https://thelounge.chat/docs/guides/reverse-proxies#apache) gives an example to use a reverse proxy with Apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/irc$ /irc/ [R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/irc/socket.io        [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /irc/(.*)       ws://127.0.0.1:9000/$1 [P,L]

RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
ProxyVia On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyAddHeaders On
ProxyPass /irc/ http://127.0.0.1:9000/
ProxyPassReverse /irc/ http://127.0.0.1:9000/

# By default Apache times out connections after one minute
ProxyTimeout 86400 # 1 day
```

It uses a subfolder, but I would rather have a subdomain. Like…

```
https://irc.domain.tld
```

Instead of…

```
https://domain.tld/irc/
```

Regex feels incredibly complex for someone who's just trying to set up a nice service for their friends… After so many failed attempts, I would really like some help! Please, pretty please?

Thanks for reading <3

Answer (score 1):

This is not about The Lounge or reverse proxy, but how Apache handles [virtual hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/). The official documentation even has examples for common setups, including [Using `Virtual_host` and mod_proxy together](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#proxy).

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName irc.example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:9000/$1 [P,L]

    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyAddHeaders On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/

    # By default Apache times out connections after one minute
    ProxyTimeout 86400 # 1 day
</VirtualHost>
```

The mod_rewrite is only required to allow both HTTP and Websocket connections. If you only need the Websocket, the configuration for it becomes a lot easier, as demonstrated in [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName irc.example.com
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```